# New XEN Server, Intel i7, Errors were encountered while processing: xen-linux-system-amd64

Tags: debian, xen, intel

I have just got a new machine to run XEN VM's on, it has an Intel i7 processor: 
- Intel Haswell Core i7-4790 3.6GHz 8MB LGA1150

### Update

[Screencast of what I am doing - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVcf0ycMJwU )

---

I have setup the host with the current 6.2.0

I have set up a new Debian 7 64bit VM and any package I try and run fails with the following errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xen-utils-common
 xen-utils-4.1
 xen-system-amd64
 xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64
 xen-linux-system-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



    Setting up xen-utils-common (4.1.4-3+deb7u2) ...
[warn] Starting Xen daemons: (warning).
invoke-rc.d: initscript xen, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing xen-utils-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xen-utils-4.1:
 xen-utils-4.1 depends on xen-utils-common (>= 4.1.4-3+deb7u2); however:
  Package xen-utils-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing xen-utils-4.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xen-system-amd64:
 xen-system-amd64 depends on xen-utils-4.1; however:
  Package xen-utils-4.1 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing xen-system-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64:
 xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64 depends on xen-system-amd64; however:
  Package xen-system-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xen-linux-system-amd64:
 xen-linux-system-amd64 depends on xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64; however:
  Package xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing xen-linux-system-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xen-utils-common
 xen-utils-4.1
 xen-system-amd64
 xen-linux-system-3.2.0-4-amd64
 xen-linux-system-amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

[Answered: Excuse my noob-ness but should it even be running an AMD package ?]

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: What were the errors? (Oh and it says 'amd64' because AMD invented the 64-bit processor instructions that Intel later used. You can ignore that.)

Answer (score 0):

Sheldon,

I did some searching on Google and came across a bug report on debian.org (Bug#709103): https://lists.debian.org/debian-kernel/2013/05/msg00478.html. This user reported something very similar to what you described above. He ran the below:

```
root@debian7:~# aptitude install xen-linux-system-amd64
```

Have you tried updating Debian first and then trying the xen installation again (ie. aptitude update && aptitude dist-upgrade)?

Good luck

Comment: Thanks Chris, Running that fails with the same error as above, anything to do with apt-get or aptitude fails. 

I am going to set up another VM and try from fresh.